# PhoneGap or Native Language

Tags: mobile, cordova

I'm going to develop **a mobile CHAT application**. And my app will run on 2 mobile platforms (iOS and Android). Its features may include:

- Add friend
- View friends onlining
- Chat and send file
- ...

I've written app for Android(Android Java) and iOS(Object-C) before. And now, I'm beginning to learn PhoneGap. I dont know what the most choice is?

I hope to receive your helps! Thanks very much!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to use Network socket for the chat application then yes performance can be a issue.

As pointed out by people earlier phonegap is for web developers who don't intend to learn objective-C or java. But again, if you wish to be involved in long term development of ios/android, objective-c and java will be the way to go. If it is just for this project then i wouldn't really recommend you taking all the hassle.

I am a very experienced web developer with strong background in c/c++ and java. I had/have to work very hard to get the native apps in ios working but i opted for native as i will be working in other projects as well.

Plus, with phonegap you have to work extremely hard in terms of css/html to give a native feel to the app.

Comment: Thanks you very much!:) I really like your advice :). Anything you want to say, I will pay attenttion ^^

Comment: ^^ in the case that you want to use PhoneGap, please also think about using a JS framework: Sencha Touch (adviced) or JQuery Mobile or JTouch or ... Titanium Appcelerator is another alternative to PhoneGap

Comment: Second point is indeed performance. Come on, he is not going to make a 3D assassin creed game killer... it's a low-rate data streaming app that does not need anything fancy on hardware side. In this context the success of the project depends on how the developer is good. So here is my 2 cents: For the app you are targeting go for phonegap (& co) it's a wise choice as you can very easily port your app (in some cases out of the box) to other platforms without much efforts on your side. Moreover, maintability gets even easier...

Comment: @CoolStraw : I don't understand wht's ur deal dude ? read the answer properly before you bring your prejudice into the picture. I have nothing against phonegap... As far as look and feel is, it was for the "Native feel" (not in context of the present app)

Comment: @Kishot Kundan : ain't got no different deal. But reading that "Plus, with phonegap you have to work extremely hard in terms of css/html to give a native feel to the app." is a valid answer bugs me as hell. Do not underestimate the technology it's beyond your tiny knowledge. The man is asking for directions do not mislead him and please give him a proper answer.

Comment: I have only given my opinion on the subject and the decision was left completely on @Let'sBi . I shared my "tiny knowledge" that's it... But I would really really really love to see someone put it effort to make a phonegap app appearence wise that feels "native". Again, with the kinda "jumpin to conclusion" nature that u have i would like to point out "It's not impossible, but why invest ur effort to make something which can be achieved for free"

Comment: Kishor do not get me wrong. I am not nagging to defend phonegap or whatsoever. I am bugged by statements made out of nonsense. I am not saying you have something against phonegap (I won't care anyway) but the best answer I could read in this topic is the one from Pham. Every technology/choice has pros & cons. State them accordingly that's all. PS: if you make one app you would want it to behave the same everywhere. it's like if facebook would make 2 apps (ios/android) with a totally different look & feel. That's bad advertising and this is not the target of phonegap and co.

Comment: Most importantly if someone wishes to pursue there career over iphone or android devlopment then there isn't much point sticking to phonegap. IT DOESN'T EVEN SUPPORT CALENDAR. Its not even in its roadmap. In most particularly with Utility apps, you need calendar's support. Again my tiny knowledge

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16349/discussion-between-coolstraw-and-kishor-kundan) shit I can't access chat from the office... I would have ripped you off ^^

Comment: Your argument fails heavily ! You still do not get it: stick to the purpose, stop looking for what is supported and what isn't. Phonegap has a gateway with an extension native interface. That means you have everything you need to do anything you want as long as on hardware and some software sides you are covered. In 2 days time we added calendar support to a phonegap app (not even full time work...). In other words; the extension model of phonegap does not forbid you from integrating any 3rd party api or app or whatsoever to reach your target. So again, throw that argument to the trash :)

Comment: no need to join chat, u ripped me here alright... c actually reading through ur comments, u have made few valid points, its ur attitude that's bugs a hell out of me.

I am all happy and praise for technologies such as phonegap bridging the platform boundaries, but that praisal should not come at a cost and it should be left to the person. After all its every individual's decision. I don't wanna put in any argument any further

Comment: Well I might have been a bit pissed off my apologies for my excessive reaction though :)

Answer (score 2):

PhoneGap is cross-platform, it helps you save extra work porting codes to different platforms. It does have the trade off that certain low level APIs cannot be accessed and per formance can be an issue.

In a chat client, performance is not so critical, I think PhoneGap is a good choice.

Comment: That is the excellent answer of this question ! Thanks Pham for being reasonable and mainstream.

Answer (score 2):

If you can write programs for both platofrms using their preferred, 'native' language, then there's no sense in using PhoneGap. PhoneGap is for web developers who don't intend to learn Java or Objective-C. However, HTML+JavaScript will always be slower and will provide a worse user experience than Java and Objective-C, simply because JavaScript wasn't designed to high-performance native application programming, but webscripting. Java was desiged for it and has a highly optimized VM on Android (designed for the usually weaker hardware in mobile phones), and Objective-C is fully native, squeezing the best possible performance out of iDevices' processors.

Comment: Wrong statement. my god.... there is no sense in using phonegap? How about effort times 2 ? The main goal of phonegap is to -almost- write once and run everywhere.

Comment: 1- I natively speak C. Not Objective-C but real C. See the language that is used to write the kernel that is running your apps on top of your phone core. And yes I am a former kernel/low-level programmer (by passion). 2- I do not care if you advice him to use oC or anything else but I do care when you highlight wrong arguments. You need to learn how to establish a balance between the requirements and the tools available to deliver a result with the following factors in mind: * Fast * Reliable * Future-proof. A technology like phonegap or sencha... fits perfectly in that context.